# PHP copy() works on localhost(wamp) but not on my real web domain

Tags: php, copy

ok so i'm trying to copy `file.xml` into another location something like `copy('file.xml',../../folder/newfile.xml)` ; it works just fine on my wamp virtual server but on my real site it doesn't. i thought that is something related to chmod and i changed the `file.xml` to 0777(with a ftp client).

is there something that i should put in my code to make it right? or what?

Comment: You should probably ask your host if `copy` is somehow restricted on their servers.

Comment: have you tried chmod 777 your target folder?

Answer (score 0):

Copy is a pretty straigtforward function.  As Mark said, it's perhaps [a host issue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#93245).

Comment: and if the my host doesn't give me permision to copy files is there a way to change this with a .htaccess ?

Comment: @kmunky - if they're disallowing the function, overriding with a `.htaccess`, while maybe possible, would likely be grounds for getting your account killed

Comment: i just read the php configuration on my account and it says nothing about copy(), but i still think that this is the only plausible cause. i'll try that function that you pointed me at. thanks

Comment: ok...so i partially discovered the problem...it's not from copy restrictions...i realized that even that i set my folder access to 0777 when i create it like so mkdir($total_path,"0777"), when i check it's chmod i get a 411 permision...do you have any idea why that happens ? thanks

Comment: Your mode should not contain quotes.  Try mkdir($total_path, 0777);

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you don't have permissions to the folder you are trying to copy to or as mentioned your host doesn't give PHP necessary permissions for copy.

Comment: a forgot to mention, first of all i create the folder that i'm copying the file in, and i create it with a chmod of 0777